# Binary file search tools

Tags: tools, linux

Is there a open-source Linux tool / utility for Linux platform that would recursively search for binary files (executable, shared / static objects, etc), in a folder and display?

Comment: What do you mean by binary file ? Is, for an instance, mp3 music file binary ?

Comment: I have mentioned in the parenthesis: executable, shared / static objects, etc. I am not interested in .mp3 or .ogg or .gif or .jpeg :).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic Unix shell commands. Not about reverse-engineering.

Comment: @perror, I believe, answer to the question helps to begin reverse-engineering a binary knowing that it belongs to 'a' architecture and one can process the binary alive on a compatible virtual or physical platform, the answer very much helps in disassembly or decompilation, it definitely helps to begin with, "...explore the principles of a system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation ...", so what if it is a basic Unix Shell Command?, requesting you to review your opinion, it is not necessary that only experts visit here.

Comment: Your question is way to basic and weak compared to the scope of this website. It could have been covered in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) with no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking for files containing executable code in a well known format, you could search using `find` and `file`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep -i "i386\|x86\|arm\|ar archive"
```

This will get you all files which `file` labeled with the processor name for i386, x86 or arm.

Note that there are many filetypes which `file` does not recognize.
It will for instance not recognize java jar files, or android apk files as executable.
Nor will it recognize raw firmware images.

What I actually usually do when researching an unknown system:

- do `find . | xargs file` to get a large list of everything
- then filter out known files, like audio, images, html, text, xml files.
- then manually inspect what is left over.
- `file` also makes lots of mistakes, i usually get quite some number of files labeled as DOS executable, which aren't, also i often see files mislabeled as DBase.

Comment: This will not find static libraries. You should add "i386\|x86\|arm\|ar\ archive"